# Import functions from table as local functions in Lua

Tags: scope, lua

I want to achieve this (import functions from util table as local values):

```
function blah () 
 local x = util.x
 local y = util.y
 ...
end
```

without having to reference each function explicitly, e.g. something like:

```
function blah()
  for name,f in util do 
    ???
  end
end
```

Unfortunately there is no local table that I could set the way one can set _G['function_name_as_string']. Ideas?

Comment: By the way, what exactly do you want to achieve by setting them as local variables?

Comment: Local variables are (usually) significantly faster to access than globals. It is often thought to be good style to cache frequently used globals (especially functions whose values are effectively constant once created) in locals to improve performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't set local variables by name. You'd have to do it explicitly.

Fyi, the reason for there not being a `_L` table similar to `_G` is because of the lexical scoping. It is possible to have the same local variable names in multiple scopes, yet they aren't the same variables. You would have to have a `setlocal("foo", xxx)` kind of thing, but Lua doesn't have that.

Comment: There is debug.setlocal but the debug library is not meant for ordinary programming.

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, I have seen an example for [metalua](http://metalua.luaforge.net/) that enables something like this. It operates on the abstract syntax tree and as a result can introduce new keywords and syntax into the language.